# Write to File and Audit Table

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to use Springbatch for a batch job that has to write to a file (Step 1) and also write the data (that was sent in the file) into an Audit Table.(step 2)

Is there any Better way other than giving the output file from Step 1 as input to Step 2 to write to DB?

The data cannot be passed in Exceution Context because it is huge.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, using a [`CompositeItemWriter`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/support/CompositeItemWriter.html).
From its javadoc

> Calls a collection of ItemWriters in fixed-order sequence.

Just create a `CompositeItemWriter` passing delegates (yours real writer: one for file and one for audit table) and register them as stream to allow restartability.

```
<bean id="fileWriter" class="path.to.filewriterClass" />
<bean id="auditTableWriter" class="path.to.auditawriterClass" />
<bean id="compositeWriter" class="path.to.CompositeItemWriter>
  <property name="delegates">
    <list>
    <bean ref="fileWriter" />
    <bean ref="auditTableWriter />
  </property>
</bean>
<step name="step1">
  <tasklet>
    <chunk reader="path.to.readerClass" writer="compositeWriter" />
      <streams>
        <stream ref="fileWriter" />
        <stream ref="auditTableWriter" />
      </streams>
  </tasklet>
</step>
```

See [official doc](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/reference/html/readersAndWriters.html) for extra information and google around for a ton of examples!

Comment: Hi Bellabax, For the AuditTableWriter I was using a Custom Itemwriter implementing the ItemWriter, but getting an exception saying that the stream is not supported.

Comment: Let it implementing itemstream